# Email address format: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: .net, email, mailmessage

I am getting following error while creating System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object.

```
Dim Message As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(mailfrom, mailto)
```

The mailTo address is in the form - a.b.c.d.@abcd.com. Is that a invalid format?

1. Can an email not contain more than one period(.) in its local part?
2. Can the local part of an email end with a period(.)?

Thank you.

Update:
The application that was giving error was targeting .net 3.5. When I tried to reproduce the error on a different solution, I found the trailing period in the local part of a.b.c.d.@abcd.com is a limitation in .net 3.5 framework but works fine in .net 4.0 and above. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's the "to" address that's causing problems?

Comment: `new MailMessage("a@b.c", "a.b.c.d@abcd.com")` doesn't throw an exception for me, so I can't reproduce this. If you could post a full repro, that would really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, I edited the question. The To address is in a.b.c.d.@abcd.com.

Comment: You'd said that already, but we don't know what the form of the from address is.

Comment: Initially i posted a.b.c.d@abcd.com and i changed it to a.b.c.d.@abcd.com - there is an extra period in the local part. The From address is valid because we use that all the time to send our emails - abcd@something.org

Comment: You should edit the rest of the description in the question to make that clear then - it's not about whether there are multiple periods.

Comment: @JonSkeet edited with precise questions.

Comment: But the first question is clearly answered by my comment, isn't it? `a.b.c.d@abcd.com` is fine.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this: `new MailMessage("a@b.c", "a.b.c.d.@abcd.com")` works for me. Could you reproduce it with a string literal like that? I wonder whether your actual value has an unprintable character in it...

Comment: The application that is sending email is in .net 3.5. Like you said, I tried to reproduce the error in separate solution (.net 4.5) but couldn't reproduce it. When I change the target framework to 3.5, the MailMessage c'tor threw the exception. So, I guess the trailing period (.) is limitation in .net 3.5.

Comment: Right - I suggest you include that in the question then. (I've reproduced it.) Looks like it's a bug in .NET 3.5, basically. But "a.b.c.d@abcd.com" is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

a.b.c.d@abcd.com is a valid format. However, according to this:

I switched from System.Web.Mail to System.Net.Mail, however I am now reconsidering that move because if I send an email to an email address in the form john.doe@yahoo.com, I receive an error message "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address". I have conducted further testing and evidently the SmtpClient class Send method does not like the period "." between the "john" and "doe". If I conduct a test with an email address in the form jdoe@yahoo.com...everything works fine.

Source: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/432854

Comment: That was in 2005 - I'm not sure I believe it even back for that early version, but it's definitely not a limitation now. The trailing `.` may well be though.